# Condition sentence. If and Had?

Tags: grammar

This is a rewriting question :

If his solicitor hadn't advised him, he wouldn't have made a serious mistake.

-> Had it not been for the advice of his solicitor.

Please explain the grammar and the answer above. I just don't understand anything.

Comment: Are you sure you mean the negative "wouldn't"? "Would" seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yes. This is the question in my textbook